# Reactivity on props Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, inertiajs

I am in the beginning of learning Vue, and having a hard time understanding how to define props etc. using the composition API.

I have a component (ACE Editor), loaded like this:

```js
<v-ace-editor
    v-model:value="currentRecord.text"
/>
```

The `v-ace-editor` needs to have the model and value loaded like this: `v-model:value`.

```js
import {computed, ref} from 'vue';
import collect from "collect.js"

const props = defineProps({
    records: {
        type: Object,
    },
})

//Get all records.
let getRecords = () => {
    return collect(props.records)
}

//Filter the records using "collect.js"
const getUnlabeledRecords = () => {
    return getRecords()
        .where('skipped', false)
        .where('processed', false);
}

//Assign all unlabeled records on the first load.
let allRecords = ref(getUnlabeledRecords());

//In order to check if "text" is empty - and if not, set a default value, load the first record into a temp. variable.
let first = allRecords.value.first();
if(first){
    first.text ??= "";
}

//Load the current record into a ref.
let current = ref(first);

//Finally, compute it.
let currentRecord = computed(() => current.value)
```

Looking at this, and coming from a backend background, it feels very bloated.

I have tried the following:

```js
let allRecords = ref(getUnlabeledRecords());
let currentRecord = computed(() => allRecords.value.first())
```

But doing this leads to me not being able to interact with the `currentRecord` - nor change the `allRecords`. This means that if for example `currentRecord.text` is `null` from the backend, my ace-editor component fails because it expects a value.

Is there another way to load in these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have to called .value of a ref when using it in the template.
So you can actually remove the computed part (last line of your ) and change your template to.

```html
<v-ace-editor
    v-model="current.text"
/>
```

Now, assuming you managed v-model correctly in v-ace-editor (if this is your own component), you should have reactivity kept when modifiying current.text from v-ace-editor.

As a side note, *computed* properties are read-only. You cannot expect a child component to modify its value by passing it with v-model.

However, you should note that updating *records* prop from parent component will not update *current*. For this, maybe you want to add a watcher on *records*.

Also, personal suggestion, but if you only really care about *currentRecord* in your component and not all records, maybe you should do the filtering from parent component and only pass currentRecord as a prop. Other personal suggestion, you can declare all your variables in your script with *const* instead of *let*. *const* prevent reassignation, but since you work with refs, you never reassign it, but you change its *value* property.